# Cropping black marks on edge of geotiffs using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geotiff-tiff, clip

Are you aware of any way to crop a geotiff while maintaining the co-ordinate information?

I am trying to crop a series of geotiffs of multi-beam data which have a black frame on one or two edges (in arcmap 10) which i can't remove, even setting the background colour to no colour does't work (it is set so that only the multibeam image is showing though).

Im not actually a 100% sure what the marks are, the data was worked in fledermaus to create DTM's and exported as geotiffs then to arc .

I've read the other entries about this problem but i not really confident on how to use gdal or code. I no longer have access to fledermaus so cannot re-edit etc.

Comment: Would simply clipping them accomplish what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

See [@SaultDon's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8563/115) to [Clipping image with Basic (ArcView) level license of ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8556)

You'll have to digitize some polygons specific to the areas you want to clip, but you won't lose your georeferencing information after executing the clip.  It doesn't require any code and just uses ArcToolbox functionality.  I'm pretty sure this will work for you.